# what is the replace code in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error:

[image: how do i resolve this problem?]

the code in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you add the complete `AppModule`? Coz your error has references to `AppRoutingModule` but I'm not able to see any references to that in there.

Comment: Do you have multiple `AppRoutingModule` defined?

Comment: No bro... @ShamPooSham

Comment: Also, the title confuses me. What do you mean by replace code?

Comment: I feel like there's some code we're missing. Mind to create a project on stackblitz.com and see if the problem persists?

Comment: try to remove the "Routes" import, also should no be like : `RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' } ])` ? 
or other component you have?

Comment: fine bro... I shall see...